# Selenium Chrome Extension Interaction

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I can load a Selenium Chromedriver extension in python. But I need to login in this extension in order to be able to use it. My question is how can I interact with this extension in order to login within it? The extension namely is the "Hoxx VPN".

Until I have the following code:

```
chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chop.add_extension("D:/01_PhD/Fogadas/chromeextension/2.2.2_0.crx")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chop)
```

Comment: See [Open a chrome extension through selenium webdriver](//stackoverflow.com/q/25557533) - the easiest solution seems to open the login/popup page URL directly in the tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium Webdriver can interact  with web pages only. Previously I have also tried it but unable to succeed.

See this as reference:

**https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7805**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Opera Webbrowser** it's latest version i.e. 70+ having the in-built vpn which can be activated easily by *selenium*

Github have the required code to operate opera using selenium